# AngularJs $transitions.onError gets invoked when clicking link twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I am in the process of moving from Angulars built in router to using `ui-router` (and it's awesome) but I have a small problem:

I basically have a "**home**" page with two child views (**Register** and **Login**) I also have some restricted pages on the application so I'm using a resolve:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
}).state('home.login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
}).state('home.register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
})

$stateProvider.state('console', {
    url: '/console',
    templateUrl: 'partials/console.html',
    controller: 'ConsoleController',
    resolve: {
        currentAuth: function(Authentication) {
            return Authentication.requireAuth();
        }
    }
});
```

Authentication is just a service I've created that checks if a user is logged into `Firebase` or not (it works as expected even though I haven't injected it into `.config`)

The function that handles any route errors:

```
.run(function($transitions, $rootScope, $state) {

$transitions.onError({}, function() {
    $rootScope.message = "You need to log in first";
    redirectError();
});

function redirectError() {
    $state.go('home', {}, { reload : true});
}});
```

I have `$state.go` in a function because AngularJS says it can't find it if I try to use it in the `onError` function but it works as intended.

So `onError` is fired every time I try to go directly to `/console` without logging in and allows me to go to that state if I am logged in so it does work perfectly fine.

My problem is whenever I click on a child link of the home page twice. It will inject the HTML in fine when I click it first, but when I click it again then it will invoke `$transitions.onError` and the error message will be displayed (`$rootScope.message`). Does anyone know why this is? The resolve function is not applied to the child states of **'home'**.

I use AngularJS 1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the transition object after clicking the same route twice, you will see "success: failed". I suppose it considers navigating to a route you are already at a failure, thus triggering the onError method. I would like clarification on this myself, since my assumption about the success property being the trigger for the method could be wrong.

Anyway, I had solved this issue before I even realized I had it. I was checking transition.$to().name for the route/s that I wanted to reject and handling those cases in an if block. I suppose another work around would be to disable the button of your currently visited route. ** or use the other transtion object methods to fulfill whatever use case you want.

Comment: Problem still exists, after all these years. wtf is going on there?